# Galaxy Nexus ringtones and notifications too quiet

Tags: audio, ringtone, samsung-galaxy-nexus

I've recently ditched an iPhone in favour of an Android, Galaxy Nexus.  Now I am missing calls and texts all the time because I simply don't hear the ring!  I have maxed all the volume sliders in settings and the volume rocker on the side, and tried the more obnoxious ringtones included stock, but it is still fairly quiet.

I'm not hard of hearing but if I'm on a tram and the phone is in my suit pocket or bag, it's just not loud enough to be heard over the ambiant noise.

Is this a common problem or it might be specific to my phone?  How can I boost the volume of ringtone and text notifications?

Comment: I don't think it's just you. I've noticed the same thing, except I'm coming from a Motorola Droid which was really _loud_.

Comment: This is a common problem with Galaxy Nexus, and most of the custom firmwares out there have this fixed, but not the official ones.

Comment: @onik what is a custom firmware where this is fixed?

Comment: @wim this one, for example: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1361108&highlight=volume+bug

Answer (score 1):

You might want to give [Volume+](http://androidaudiohacks.com/?p=149) a try (scroll down for download link).

Answer (score 0):

The default ringtones are fairly quiet. Install some standalone ringtones or else grab a copy from your device and run them through a program to increase their volume before placing back onto the phone.